# Cannot convert string to float

Tags: python, string, floating-point, floating-point-conversion, floating-point-exceptions

I am getting information from a csv, I need to take a field which in theory is a float, but can come empty, I'm this function which takes the row [i] where the float is, and should return the float,

```
def fun(x):
    if not(x):
        x=0
        x=float(x)
    else:
        x = float(x)
    return x
```

but when i try it throws me this error  tells me "float () argument must be a string or a number"

Comment: try to fix your formatting, that's not legal python as it is.

Comment: what are you passing as x?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham for example fun(row[11]), and row[11] in the csv is empty,

Comment: yes but are you always positive row[11] will be able to be parsed as a float? I think a try/except would be much better

Comment: @PadraicCunningham for example, height could be like this, first line empty, but second line, 14.4, and so

Comment: so what type **is** `x`?  Add a `print(type(x))` as the very first line of `fun`, and show us what it says!-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, how about

```
def fn(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return 0.0
```

Comment: still tells me "float() argument must be a string or a number"

Comment: @Tabbz,  are you passing a list, a tuple, etc,,? You need  to `print row[11] `and see exactly what you are passing

Comment: @Tabbz,`except (ValueError,TypeError):` will catch the TypeError but you should really see what row[11] is when you get the error. What does` print row[11]`  show right before the error?

Comment: im printing like this print 'row[11] '+str(row[11]) print 'row[12] '+str(row[12])                    print 'row[13] '+str(row[13]), just you can know what im printing, but if i print only row[11] prints like " 
"

Comment: what exactly are you trying to cast to float?

Comment: row[11] are weight, in the csv several fields of this are empty, but others have numbers, the problem is those fields that are empty

Comment: ok so just catch the TypeError also, that will catch the empty strings `except (ValueError,TypeError):`

Answer (score -1):

```
def fun(x):
    try:
        x = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        x = 0
    return x

print fun("1")
print fun(' ')
```

Output:

```
1.0
0
```